# Sending post variables to iOS form

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am trying to send a username and password to a website which is normally done through a form. The server however is redirecting me to a login page, which usually occurs when the username and password is wrong. The username is in the form of an email address and the password is a string.

I do currently have access to the website as the developer is away to check that the values are being processed correctly. Can anyone see any obvious errors in the code I have created below?

Please note I have removed the URL from the example code for privacy reasons.

```
// Validate login
-(bool)validateLogin{

    // Initialize URL to be fetched
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"removedurl"];

    NSString *post = @"username=example1%40example.com&password=example2";

    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

    // Initalize a request from a URL
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[url standardizedURL]];

    //set url
    [request setURL:url];
    //set http method
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    //set request length
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    //set request content type we MUST set this value.
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    //set post data of request
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSLog(@"%@", [request allHTTPHeaderFields]);

    //initialize a connection from request
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    _connection = connection;    
    //start the connection
    [connection start];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I do this         NSURLResponse *theResponse = [[NSURLResponse alloc] init];
        NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&theResponse error:&error];
        
        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResp = ((NSHTTPURLResponse *)theResponse);

Comment: This pattern of connection is not quite correct: you don't set delegate to NSURLConnection object, to catch the callback. And `[connection start]` is not necessary.

Comment: See edit in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This string is not correct `NSString *post = @"username=example1%40example.com&example2";`
After ampersand you have to provide key=value.

`@"key1=value1&key2=value2";`

Example of working code:

In .h file set delegate:

```
@interface Controller <NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>
```

In .m file:

```
- (void)login {
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:kRequestTimeOut];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
    NSString *params = @"key1=value1&key2=value2";
    request.HTTPBody = [params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    _data = [NSMutableData data];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [_data appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    //Parse your '_data' here.
}
```

Comment: Sorry that typo occurred when i replaced the true password with an example to use in this question. The problem still exists.

Comment: This code worked fine, I have discovered the reason the POST was not working was because the API requires cookies to be enabled. Do you know of a way to enable cookies to be used by the application to create a session?

Comment: You have `NSHTTPCookieStorage` object. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/Reference/Reference.html